# Can we store the data collected by executing tcl script into a database (postgresql)? If yes how?

Tags: postgresql, tcl

In my project I need to simulate social network community members and their activities. I think to represent the members as nodes and need to store the count of their postings, feedback etc. Can we store the data collected by executing tcl script into a database (PostgreSQL)? If yes can anyone explain how  it is?

Comment: [Quick-start guide to use of PostgreSQL with Tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10548).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use SQlite3, a much lighter alternative to a full Postgres installation.

see https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [OpenACS](http://www.openacs.org) - it's a social networking community software and is written using TCL and Postgresql (or Oracle if you prefer)